# Cookie in client-side NodeJs

Tags: node.js, cookies

I have a cookie obtained through cookie-parser in server side.

```
    const app = express();
    app.use(cookieParser());
    exports.app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('Cookies: ', req.cookies.clientID);
        let clientId_cookie = req.cookies.clientID;
exports.clientId_cookie = clientId_cookie;
        console.log(clientId_cookie);
        next();
    });
```

I need to use it in another file on the client side. I have tried to export and use it but its value is undefined.
How could I do it?

If I export the variable, the way I try to get the value in another file (table.helpers.js) (I need that value to make queries) is the following:

```
var client_coockie = require('../app').clientcoockie;
```

Or how can I access that variable outside of that function?

I hope your help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide code where you show how you try to use that cookie, but it won't work anyway since you can't use cookie like that. Client-side code is executed in browser so he won't be able to get it in that way.

In other to access cookies on front end you want to use `document.cookie` to retrieve cookies([more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)), you could also use library like [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)
to simplify things.

I assume that you know how to set cookie on server-side.

And also remember that you shouldn't put any sensitive information inside cookie or if you really need to do that then use some form of encryption.

Comment: I tried this:

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

But i have this error:
ReferenceError: document is not defined

 Im trying to get the cookie value for use in a query

Comment: I changed the question showing how I try to get the value

Comment: And if I just wanted to access that variable outside of the function?

Comment: Wait do you try to get cookie on the client or on the server side?

Comment: Because if you try on server side you don't have access to document, while on client side you have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will do it from the client side and I will pass the value as a parameter of the function.